# How to add to a conditional variable for comparison

Tags: php

At this point in time, the below variables are set at the values shown and I need to compare:

(Pseudo code)

```
if $foo is > 0 AND that $i == $bar +1.
```

This is just a simplified example.  In my code these variables are different at various times.

I'm not having any success figuring out how to do this comparison.  Any help is appreciated.

```
$i = 4;
$foo = 4;
$bar = 3;

if($foo > 0 && ($i == ($bar + 1))) {
    echo 'do something';
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Close.  Count your parentheses.

Comment: No that isn't working either.  The missing parentheses was my typo just now.

Comment: Now your code DOES work.  Just tested.

Comment: Were you expecting this: http://3v4l.org/mQcUG

Comment: Please specify what your goal is what you have tried and what you get!

Comment: I found my error.  In another part of the code I was changing one of the variables for a different function which was making $i always be +2 over $bar making my conditional statement never be true.  Thanks everyone for the assist.  Confirming the condition should work help me dig deeper to find the issue.

Comment: @BitBug Congraze you just have debugged your own code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly think your code should work (after the parentheses fixes), but whatever your real logic is instead of the example code you gave, you can try wrapping all the logic areas.

```
$i = 4;
$foo = 4;
$bar = 3;

if(($foo > 0) && ($i == ($bar + 1))) {
    echo 'do something';
}
```